# Проблема с BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android

Кусок из манифеста

```
`<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">  
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                </action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME">
                </category>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
`
```

Cам класс:

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootReciver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Тест", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Нотификация не вызывается, как и Log.d и прочее. Иначе говоря не выполняется. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно вы забыли

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```